# Checking locations in grid world

Tags: java, gridworld

How would I check to see if two spaces in front of a bug class is a clear spot with nothing on it and also does not go over the boundary? Right now this is what I have

```
public void act()
{
  if(canMove())
  {
     Location loc = getLocation();
     Location nextLocation = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
     nextLocation = nextLocation.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
     if (nextLocation == null)
     {
       move();
       move();
     }

  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as the bug does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `if(nextLocation != null)`. We don't want the bug to jump off of the board (to a `null` space). This is from as much as I can remember about `GridWorld`; I do not have the program on hand.

Comment: The bug now moves, but how do i get it to stay in the bounded grid?

Answer (score 0):

What you have has two problems.

1. Doesn't check if the next location is in the grid, which you knew
2. Didn't move to the location that you found. Move() just moves in the current direction, regardless of whether its in the grid or not. So calling it twice moved forward twice, but did not use the location that you found to be in the grid.

Try changeing your code to:

```
        public void act()
        {
           if(canMove())
           {
               Location loc = getLocation();
               Location nextLocation = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
               nextLocation = nextLocation.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
               Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid(); 

               if (gr.isValid(nextLocation))
               {
                   moveTo(nextLocation);
               }
               else
                   move(); //This could be move() so you only move forward one 
                          //space or turn() to turn 

           }
        }
```